# Android MVP Proper Way to Release Presenter

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, architecture, mvp

I am working with MVP architecture and I'm stuck on how to proper release the presenter. First, let me tell you guys what is happening.

**PROBLEM**

1) My presenter make an async server request.

2) When I receive the server response, my view (fragment) was already detached but I still have its instance hold on my presenter (which can causes memory leaks) and I call a method from View to set some data I received from the server.

3) Inside my view I use the context from *getActivity()* method, which in this stage will return **null**.

**HOW I TRIED TO FIX THIS PROBLEM**

1) When I detach the fragment I call a *release()* method on my presenter. Inside this method I thought about setting the instance of my view to null. This would work but then I would need to add null checks literally everywhere in my presenter checking whether my view was already set to null or not. Doesn't seems to be the best approach.

2) In my view (fragment), check whether *getActivity()* is null before using it. But it doesn't fix the memory leak problem and I would need to add this check literally everywhere in my Fragment(s);

---

Do you guys have an alternative for that? Is that a proper way to release my presenter when my fragment is detached in a way that whenever my presenter call a method on my view I will be sure that view is attached to an Activity? Is EventBus a good approach for that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one of the main goals of the presenter layer is to be Android Framework independent, that means that you don't have in imports any of the packages from Android Framework, making it pure Java class. You should make your `Activity` or `Fragment` implements the `ActivityView` interface or `FragmentView` interface, ant let concrete `Activity` or `Fragment` implement that interface. Now, in the `onCreate()` you create an instance of the presenter and pass as an argument the View (Activtity or Fragment), and in Presenter class you will have `ActivityView` or `FragmentView` reference, initializing it through the constructor, something like this:

**Activity.java**

```
public class Activity implements ActivityView {
    ...
    private Presenter mPresenter;

    public void onCreate() {
         // some other code

         mPresenter = new Presenter(this);

         // some other code
    }
```

**Presenter.java**

```
    public class Presenter {
         private ActivityView mActivityView;


         public Presenter(ActivityView activityView) {
           this.mActivityView = activityView;
         }
}
```

Now you can call the methods in the `Activity` or `Fragments`, but those methods must be listed in the interface. In case your are your RxJava2, you can have `CompositeDisposable` object in the `Presenter`, adding your network calls to that disposable, and in proper lifecycle methods from `Activity` or `Fragment`, your can call `dispose()` method on `compositeDisposable`, through `Presenter` of course. In that way you will clean any ongoing network operations, making it not update the UI if the UI is not present. Hope this answer helps you :)

Comment: Hi @RadoVidjen, Thanks for the reply!
Yea I'm doing exactly as you said. I have the presenter fully independent of Android components and all communication between Presenter and View are done with use of interfaces. When I say I call a view method from Presenter I mean my presenter call a method listed on my view interface.

I was thinking about avoiding RxJava as I want to implement LiveData in a later stage so that would make RxJava a bit useless (by my understanding which is limited as I didn't search a lot about RxJava yet). Am I correct? Would u have other suggestion not using RxJava?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting memory leaked? Because if you use the interface for communication, i think that is loosely coupling, that means that if View is gone, the presenter will also became null.. maybe im wrong, but your can test that with LeakCanary. In case of RxJava, i think you can combine it with LiveData, you just need to do the research a bit, to see how those two works together. In any case, if you are Using the Retrofit for networking, you shoud add the RxJava2 adapter, as it will make it much easier to do async tasks, and pass response ti the main thread.

Comment: Yea I'm sure it's getting leaked cause I'm already using LeakCanary :/

Comment: Yea I think I'll have to have a look at RxJava then. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There will be definately a leak, SInce you are holding ActivityView which is actually an Activity object (since your Activity has implemented the interface), the best wasy is to put null check before calling the view methods and i guess thats pretty standard.

Comment: Or, another way is to use `WeakReference<View>`, so i guess when view gets destroyed, its `WeakReference<View>` gets eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: But in this case (using WeakReference) I still need to add null checks everywhere in my presenter, right?

Comment: I really can`t say it without code, if you can provide source that would be nice.